zsh: command not found: sudo
There is a problem. I enter the sudo command in the terminal and get
zsh: command not found: sudo

I'm entering
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Everything works fine, but as soon as I start the terminal again, the error returns
My PATH
/usr/bin:/Users/falsehuman/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/falsehuman/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/falsehuman/Library/Android/sdk/emulator:/usr/local/opt/postgresql@14/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/falsehuman/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/bin



It should find sudo with that PATH, since it's located in /usr/bin, and this is the first directory in the path.

Try the command, where sudo and let us know the output.

The screenshot shows a completely different PATH, which doesn't make much sense. I think you need to go through all the shell initialization files that you've modified or created, and clean them up or just start over. You can find the names of those files in the zsh(1) man page.

@LincDavis /usr/bin/ is in the PATH shown in the screenshot. But something is of for sure.
